# RAZOR and prepending text in href

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm learning RAZOR.

I need to make an href tag unique, by adding a letter to the start of the #ref:

eg.

```
<a href="#p23">
```

In Razor, to populate the href tag from my model, I have:

```
<a href="#p@item.ID">
```

However, Razor doesn't recognise @item.ID, unless it has no characters in front of it.

```
<a href="#p @item.ID">
```

But that then invalidates the href.

Is there a way for me to add the letter 'p' to this, and still allow RAZOR to add the ID of the item?

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixit

just put brackets around the item, i.e.

```
<a href="#p@(item.ID)">
```

you can do this across all of the razor syntax where required to mix/match

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap it in parenthesis to aid the parser:

```
<a href="#p@(item.ID)">
```

Answer (score 1):

In VB enclose the variable with brackets: `"#p@(item.ID)"`
in c# it's either the same or use curly brackets.